# PHPExcel $objWriter->save() fails

Tags: php, apache2, phpexcel

I am creating an Excel file based on records from a database with PHPExcel and am facing an odd problem when generating it on a large data set. I have narrowed it down to a single problem-causing line:

```
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

It just spits out a blank file instead of the expected workbook. Also, the effect is similar if I try to save the result into a local file instead of redirecting to the browser - no file is ever created.

The kicker is that it works perfectly for a smaller data set (smaller = up to 200 rows, larger = up to 2000 rows, up to 20 columns in both cases). It also works fine on another (development) server with an *EXACT SAME, 100% identical*, large dataset.

I do have the `save()` call wrapped in a try-catch but no exception is raised. Executing `memory_get_peak_usage()` right before going for `save()` tells me that it was using 24MB, and I have `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` earlier in the script. Also, monitoring memory usage on the server while running the script does not show any significant increase either.

Any tips for debugging it?

Edit: there are no errors in apache logs, however I did notice that the relevant line in access logs says:

```
10.1.1.1 - - [01/Jun/2011:08:35:03 -0400] "GET /get_excel.php HTTP/1.1" 200 16386
```

The odd part is the last column - size. The file I actually get to download is always empty - exactly 0 bits, not 16386.

Comment: Do you have anything in the error.log from the webserver?

Comment: no errors from the webserver.

Comment: This 16386 bits are probably with all the header information etc. Better check with e.g. Firebug what exactly is sent. Although this alone will probably not solve your problem.

Comment: I read here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#common that this number does not include header info. Also, while debugging it for memory usage, where I echo the usage info after the headers but before save(), this number was 27 - much more sensible. Mind you, 16386 is too small for my file. Based on what I get from the working server, it should be more like 70-80KB.

Comment: Does it work when you write the file locally and then download the file with e.g. FTP? Can you open the file then? I had the same problem once too but I can't remember how exactly I solved it. It could be that I didn't have php-xml installed.

Comment: no, when i try to create the file locally it does not get created at all. i doubt it's missing php-xml or anything, as I can create excel files just fine with a different dataset.

Comment: Have you tried to identify when the file fails?  At what row count?  It might be content related, rather than size.

Comment: run time exceeded is the most likely explanation then

Comment: @Orblink - if it was content related, it should be throwing an exception that SaltyNuts could catch and report

Comment: I tried running it on a different server but on the exact same database - and the bugger did run. so it's not content related since the same content works fine on another server. how can I find out which row it fails at? from the app level the last command i run is save(), can I get inside of it somehow?

Comment: runtime limit is set to 2000 seconds (overkill, but to be sure), this script dies after ~30 seconds. i do have other scripts that take longer than 30 seconds to run, so the time limit has been tested and is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the feedback you gave in the comments I think you do not meet all the requirements. You can find the list of the requirements [here on the phpexcel website](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Requirements&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: if i don't have the requirements, how am I able to create Excel files from other sets of data, with the same script on the same server?

Comment: It could be that the maximum run-time is set too small for your PHP script. As you can see it takes sometimes several minutes to generate a file: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/230867

Comment: the timeout time is definitely longer than it takes to run.