# Getting error with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to export mysql database table in excel i.e. in XLS format, i have try ths php code for getting result in excel format but because of some reason or some missing term i can't get it done, here is my php code:

```
<?php

// connection with the database
$dbcon = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","mim");

if($dbcon)
{
    mysql_select_db("mydb", $dbcon);
}
else
{
    die('error connecting to the database');
}

// require the PHPExcel file
require 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$query = "
    SELECT name
    FROM usermaster
    WHERE date between '2013-01-01' AND '2013-03-01'
";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());         

// Create a new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name');

// Loop through the result set
$row = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $col = 0;
    foreach($row as $name) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$row,$name);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}

// Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myFile.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit();

?>
```

Getting an empty page......any kind of help would be appreciated and acceptable also...

Comment: Please learn proper indentation before you inflict your code on other people.

Comment: see http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/250120

Comment: Maybe yu have a problem with environment config; see this other stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201176/phpexcel-objwriter-save-fails

Comment: Did you check the logs for any error?

Comment: In case the question is still open I think the root cause is your variable $row is used for the row number as well as for the mysql row, in line $row = mysql... you're reassigning the variable from previous line

Answer (score 0):

setCellValue() expects an Excel cell address (e.g. A1, B2, C3, where the column ID is the letter ID, followed by the row number) as the first argument. You're using numbers (starting with 0) for your column ID's.

Instead of setting the initial column ID to 0, set it to 'A':

```
$row = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($row as $name) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$row,$name);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
```

Comment: OK, start with some basic debugging... save to a file rather than php://output, and put some echo statements in your code to see what values it's writing to which cells

Comment: Hey mark i refer ur answers and comments while getting knowledge abt ths concept by referring different questions on ths  u hv very good knowledge in ths, pls help me out......

Comment: I'm trying to help you - that's why I'm suggesting some basic debugging to try and identify exactly where your problem is

Comment: What has your debugging shown? Is it displaying each cell address, and the value to be stored in that cell? If not, check that your SQL is actually returning data

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27233/discussion-between-ankit-sharma-and-mark-baker)